# How to store CFUUIDRef objects in NSArray with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm confused with ARC. I can create CFUUIDRef and I can manage the reference count via CFRetain and CFRelease. How do I add them to an NSArray and pass ownership to it?

```
CFUUIDRef *uuid = ...;

[arr setObject:myobj forKey:(__bridge id)uuid];

[arr removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)uuid];

id myobj = [arr objectForKey:(__bridge id)uuid];
```

Is the above the correct way to set, remove and retrieve? If I remove an entry from this array, would the CFUUIDRef automatically be released or do I have retrieve each object and CFRelease them myself?

Comment: You seem to be dealing with a dictionary, not an array. Do you mean to be discussing an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Ken Wong's answer, but I think you you should use `(__bridge_transfer id)` since you want to transfer ownership of the `CFUUIDRef` to the array. The object will be automatically released (but not necessarily deallocated) when removed from the array or when the array is deallocated.

```
NSMutableArray *array = /* assume this exists */;
CFUUIDRef uuid = /* assume this exists */;
[array addObject: (__bridge_tranfer id) uuid];
NSLog(@"Before = %@", uuid);
CFRelease(uuid);

// The CFUUIDRef "lives on" in the array
uuid = (__bridge CFUUIDRef) [array lastObject];
NSLog(@"After = %@", uuid);

// The UUID is deallocated (`uuid` is now an invalid reference)
[array release];
```

Comment: OK. Is it mean that I should not use `(__bridge_transfer id)` if the CFUUID still need to be used eventhough the uuid is removed from the array? Should I just use `(__bridge id)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special when adding or removing CFUUIDRef to the array as ARC will take care of it. If you have access to the 2011 WWDC videos, you can watch the "Objective-C Advancements in Dept". Starting at minute 41:40, there is a topic about CF Recipes for ARC. No CF memory management involved when you use __bridge and ARC may retain and release the value.

```
NSMutableArray *cfArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
[cfArray addObject:(__bridge id)uuid];
id myStr = [cfArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"My UUID:%@", myStr);
[cfArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"My UUID after remove from array:%@", myStr);
CFRelease(uuid);
```